# PHP notice when instantiating different objects with constant

Tags: php, constants

I understand you cannot duplicate constant. I am just confused as to why it does not work with different objects.

In one of my project I used them to pass settings to my object.

Here is an example:

```
class someClass {

    function __construct($config) {
        define("PRIVATE_KEY", $config['private_key']);
    }
}
```

and here is how I create the objects

```
$objectA = new someClass($config['A']);
$objectB = new someClass($config['B']); //ERROR!!
```

I get the error:

> Constant PRIVATE_KEY already defined

Most people that get this error had included the same constant multiple times.

In My case they are being used in separate objects. I will add some check to make sure they are not being redefined. but I am still curious to know why this happening.

Aren't object disposed/destroyed when no longer used?

Comment: An object should not modify global space when instantiated - encapsulation (i.e. isolation between things) is a key tenet of OO programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, objects are destroyed at some point, but `define` declarations are global and persist until they are undefined. Your code is defining the same constant twice.

Private properties, static properties, or maybe [class constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) are more appropriate for what you're attempting to do since they are encapsulated within the object.

```
class someClass {

    private $private_key;

    // constructor
    function __construct($config) {
        $this->private_key = $config['private_key'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'd want it to be static if passing it into the constructor - that would make it the same for all objects, and thus would defeat the purpose of passing it that way. Given the OP is passing something into the constructor, I expect an instance property would be appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks. On that basis I'd make the property lower/camel case, too. +1

Comment: Haha, yeah I just thought the same. Edited!

Comment: Thanks guys you made me realise I was misusing it, dont you need to add the const like the docs you linked `const CONSTANT = 'constant value'`, and when is it useful to use define() for constant

Comment: You can't use a class CONSTANT if you want to pass the value into the constructor.  You must set the CONSTANT value when it's declared.  I almost never use define() myself, but I can see using it in config files if the framework I'm using doesn't have another method.

Comment: exactly, I have seen it in framework as well. You have answered all my question thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What are you using PRIVATE_KEY for? Is it supposed to be an instance variable? If so, you shouldn't use define() because its scope is global. You could instead do `$this->private_key = $config['private_key']`.

Comment: private_key was just an example, but you have a valid point +1